# Problems to query last entry in DynamoDB - Always endup with NULL

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am a beginner in AWS DynamoDb and am stuck now.  I am writing a Lambda Function in node.js to query items from DynamoDb. DeviceID is the Partition Key. The idea is to query the last entry. The challenge is that I always have a “null” outcome.

Please help me move forward. Any suggestion, tip,… is more than welcome. Really appreciate that.

Here is the code of my lambda :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function getLastAliine3(deviceID) {
  const params = {
    TableName: 'AliineTable',
    IndexName: 'deviceID-Ux-index',
    key: {
      deviceID: deviceID
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'deviceID= :dID',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':dID': 'deviceID'
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    Limit: 1
  }


  try {
    const { Item } = await docClient.query(params).promise()
    return Item
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("DDB ERROR MG: ", err)
  }
}

module.exports = getLastAliine3
```

Comment: `Items` instead of `Item`. And `key` is a redundant attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':dID': 'deviceID'
    },
```

You're passing the string 'deviceId' to the Query instead of the value of your variable. This should fix the problem:

```js
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':dID': deviceID
    },
```

Comment: @MiguelGil If this helped, feel free to accept the answer using the little tick under the vote number so this question is marked as answers and future readers know this helped you :)